# SQL server- How to automatically know something inserted or updated in the database table

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2008, windows-services

I am creating a windows service in the C#. This windows service is using a timer and this timer hit SQL database table on every 1 minute to check if something is newly inserted or updated in the database table. It is working absolutely fine for me but there is some performance drawback as I am hitting database on every 1 minute. So I would like to know whether there is any approach using which immediately I could know ok now a record has been inserted or updated in my table. I do not wants to hit database on every 1 minute. Any help would be highly appreciable.

Comment: You could use [Query Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx) to be notified when data changes. This is a "push" model instead of "pull".

Comment: You can also look into Triggers.

Comment: What do you want to do when data is inserted or changed?  If you're just going to do some logging or data massaging within the database, [TRIGGERs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) would get my vote.

Comment: Yes Trigger option was there but unfortunately we can not use Trigger as a restriction of my project.